# Error in output of a simple SAX parser

Tags: java, xml, saxparser

I saw an example in mykong - http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-sax-parser/
I tried to make it work for the xml file (below) by making the following modifications to the code in the above page -

```
1 - Have only two if blocks in startElement() and characters() methods.
2 - Change the print statements in above methods, ie 
    FIRSTNAME and First Name = passenger id
    LASTNAME and Last Name = name
```

The problem is - In the output, I see the word passenger instead of the value of passenger id. How do i fix that ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root xmlns:android="www.google.com">

<passenger id="001">
<name>Tom Cruise</name>
</passenger>

<passenger id="002">
<name>Tom Hanks</name>
</passenger>

</root>
```

**Java Code**

```
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;
import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

public class ReadXMLFileSAX{

public static void main(String argv[]) {

try {

SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();

DefaultHandler handler = new DefaultHandler() {

boolean bfname = false;
boolean blname = false;

public void startElement(String uri, String localName,String qName, 
            Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {

    System.out.println("Start Element :" + qName);

    if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("passenger id")) {
        bfname = true;
    }

    if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("name")) {
        blname = true;
    }

}

public void endElement(String uri, String localName,
    String qName) throws SAXException {

    System.out.println("End Element :" + qName);

}

public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) throws SAXException {

    if (bfname) {
        System.out.println("passenger id : " + new String(ch, start,   length));
        bfname = false;
    }

    if (blname) {
        System.out.println("name : " + new String(ch, start, length));
        blname = false;
    }

}

 };

   saxParser.parse("c:\\flight.xml", handler);

 } catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
   }

   }

}
```

Comment: Can we see your code, pls ?

Comment: @BrianAgnew - added the code now. Please let me know if it anything else is required. 
Thanks

Comment: The answer is here - 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13818129/how-do-i-parse-my-simple-xml-file-with-java-and-sax

Answer (score 1):

In the startElement, when it's for "passenger", Attributes argument you get will have that value.

```
public void startElement(String uri, String localName,
    String qName, Attributes attributes)
        throws SAXException {
    if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("passenger") && attributes != null){
        System.out.println(attributes.getValue("id"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually I don't understand the main code properly. I modified my code (below), but i still can't see passenger id. 

>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>public void startElement(String uri, String localName,String qName, 
                Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
 
  System.out.println("Start Element :" + qName);
  
  if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("passenger id")) {
     System.out.println("Passenger: " + attributes.getValue("id"));
  }
   

  if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("passenger id")) {
   bfname = true;
  }
 
  if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("name")) {
   blname = true;
  }

   
 }

Comment: I have updated the code to use qName in startElement. It compares and prints the passenger id.

Comment: I changed localName to qName, but i get the same problem -  there is no id, only passenger word is printed.

Comment: What implementation of SAXParserFactory and SAXParser you're using? It works clean with my default implementation coming with Java 7.