# Extracting child elements of an XML in Java

Tags: java, xml, extract

I have a requirement where I have to extract parts of XML child nodes and use it to generate reports.

Here is an example of the sample XML code :

```
<A>
 <B>
  <C>
   <D>
   </D>
   <D>
   </D>
  </C>
 </B>
 <B>
  <C>
   <D>
   </D>
  </C>
 </B>
 <B>
  <C>
  </C>
 </B>
</A>
```

I want to extract all the elements with B as XML tag name and use that to create reports. Could someone please explain how we can extract all the elements .

PS: These extracted elements should also have their child elements in it.

Comment: You can use any java xml api to do this. Look online.

Comment: @Mahesh checkout this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13818129/how-do-i-parse-my-simple-xml-file-with-java-and-sax You are looking for the class SaxParser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple example using the [Document Object Model](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/dom/index.html) to traverse the XML file:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document document = documentBuilder.parse(new File("input.xml"));
NodeList bNodes = document.getElementsByTagName("B");
for(int i = 0; i < bNodes.getLength(); i++) {
    Element bElement = (Element) bNodes.item(i);
    NodeList cNodes = bElement.getElementsByTagName("C");
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jsoup to do this, it is a very simple to use api and there are library documentations

Downlaod: http://jsoup.org/download

Docs: http://jsoup.org/cookbook/introduction/parsing-a-document